# Popup on hover with clickable links

Tags: html, popup, hover

I want to make a popup on hover, on which we can click links. Sort of like when you hover an user in Facebook, you have options like add friend and all that. How to do that?

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165797/how-to-create-a-hovering-pop-up

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery, Google for `jquery tooltip`

One great tooltip with jQuery is the [flowplayer tooltip](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/slide.html). It allows you to put custom html in the tooltip box.